# Offline Notification through pusher gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications, offline, pusher

I have done online notification using pusher(notification gets displayed when user is online).I want to make offline notification using pusher or some other gem to show unread notifications.
Anyone having knowledge regarding this please share.

Comment: I think you can use mailboxer gem https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer for offline notification.

Comment: I want a offline notification not through mail,but as in fb offline notification,in my case i should be notified that these new appointments(in my case i want to get notified whenever appointment object is created) have been created when i was not logged in .

Comment: mailboxer is not just used to send mail, it's an messaging system within your application. it stores messages in db so you can use this to send message(notification) to your user whenever appointment object is created. Notification panel will show user.mailbox.inbox